# How can we pass parameters to an already built Vue JS app?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vuejs2

We have a Vue app that connects to a Web Service and get's some data. The web service URL is different, depending on the location we install the app on.

I first thought of using `.env` files, but later I realized these files get injected into the minified `.js` files.

Having this in my `main.js` was very convenient in the case of `.env` files:

```js
Vue.prototype.ApiBaseUrl = process.env.VUE_APP_APIBASEURL
Vue.prototype.PrintDocsFolder = process.env.VUE_APP_PRINTDOCSFOLDER
Vue.prototype.TicketPrintWSocket = process.env.VUE_APP_TICKETPRINTWSOCKET
```

The app is already built. I don't want to build the app for each of the hundred locations we have to deploy to. I'm not sure about the "official" approach for this.

Is there any out of the box solution in Vue that can allow this configuration? Basically we need to have a file in the root folder of the built app, and read values for our `Vue.prototype.VARIABLES`.

We are using `vue-cli` 3.

Comment: If you want to avoid rebuilding the entire project, cant you just search/replace the variables in an automized way? with `sed`, for example

Answer (score 4):

Like others have said, you can do this at runtime via a network request. If you don't know where you're deploying to until you're live, you'll need to do something like this.

Alternatively, you can do this at an infrastructure and networking level. Sometimes for A/B testing systems, that's how it's done.

Alternatively, you can do this at build time. I've done both... for static assets like images, sometimes you cannot do this at runtime and you need to replace the public urls at build time. For the network request approach, fetching a static json file with the mappings you host is a definite possibility.

You were very close with the idea of using `.env` files.

### Build-time approach with Vue CLI

In Vue CLI, you get to use the Webpack's DefinePlugin for free by specifying variables in your .env files prefixed as such: `VUE_APP_THE_API_URL` and then using it like `process.env.VUE_APP_THE_API_URL`. [Docs](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#using-env-variables-in-client-side-code).

#### Usage

In your source, use `process.env.VUE_APP_THE_API_URL` and .env files. Reference your API url in your source code as `process.env.VUE_APP_THE_API_URL` and then you should use the `.env` files, like you were planning to, to switch between the dev-only value and a production-only value.

The production-only value is gonna be fake and very unique so that when you find + replace it, it will be distinct.

#### Find + Replace the fake API_URL you built with

After you're done building your application for production, you're going to loop over a mapping file (json, js, whatever) which contains the API urls you're going to deploy to.

You'll use the filesystem and find + replace to replicate your app as many times as you need before doing a deploy via S3, fastly, etc. You can do this in a `bash` script or using `node + execa` or `node + fs`.

#### Why you might need to do this

I had to do this at build time because modifying certain assets is not possible at runtime due to optimizations done by webpack loaders where they hard-code things like the public path so it is faster. With hundreds of API/CDN urls, it would be extremely inefficient to rebuild the application over and over.

### How Vue CLI does it (if you don't wanna do `VUE_APP_*`)

Vue CLI is ontop of webpack and this is kind of an advanced use case, so you'll want to set `configureWebpack` inside of `vue.config.js` and point that to a `require('webpack.config.js')` file. You want to do this in Webpack or just within your build process (bash, node, gulp, whatever).

Vue CLI 3 is tied to the major webpack version. Right now that's Webpack 4. I'm going to give you the Webpack 4 answer for your problem, but I think they're changing the plugin name in Webpack v5.

#### Define Plugin

The plugin you want is the [DefinePlugin](https://v4.webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/). Just do the above steps, but you'd be manually setting `{ plugins: [ new DefinePlugin() ] }` with the options you want. You'd do this if you didn't wanna do `VUE_APP_*` as the prefix to your env variables.

Answer (score 2):

If there are **literally 100's** of locations where the app is supposed to be deployed with different APIs/params for each location `AND YOU DON'T WANT TO LEAVE ANY TRACE OF THE WHOLE DATA` apart from the variables which are necessary for proper functioning of the app, I would have personally stored all the different params in one central database and create one single **common API** which is able to decide which params to feed to which particular deployment. So that at initial app load, the app would `just have to make 1 extra API to call to get the correct params`. (provided there is some unique identifier for each deployment).

For example, if the unique identifier is the **domain name** over which the app is served.
You can store the params like this in the database:

```
+-------------------+----------------------------+-----------------+--------------------+--+
| domainName        | ApiBaseUrl                 | PrintDocsFolder | TicketPrintWSocket |  |
+-------------------+----------------------------+-----------------+--------------------+--+
| example.com       | http://api-base-url-1.com/ | print-doc-1     | ticket-print-1     |  |
+-------------------+----------------------------+-----------------+--------------------+--+
| secondExample.com | http://api-base-url-2.com/ | print-doc-2     | ticket-print-2     |  |
+-------------------+----------------------------+-----------------+--------------------+--+
| thirdExample.com  | http://api-base-url-3.com/ | print-doc-3     | ticket-print-3     |  |
+-------------------+----------------------------+-----------------+--------------------+--+
```

then at app load, you can make a axios (Promise based HTTP client) call and pass the `current domain name` as a param like this:

```
const details = await axios.get('/common-api-with-all-the-details', {
params: {
    domainName: location.hostname
});
```

This common API should match the domain with db and fetch the correct record accordingly.

**Advantages:**

- You never need to rebuild the app or config the environment variables
  individually.
- You will always be in control over which params to feed
  to which particular deployment.
- You can CHANGE/UPDATE the params on
  the FLY.
- Your whole data store is not public.

**Disadvantages:**

- Requires one extra server setup.
- 1 extra API call at app's initial load.

**Other approaches:**

- You can avoid the use of database (if your dataset is not too large) by storing all your details in an array. Then on every **COMMON API** call, you can match the domain name against the array ([lodash](https://lodash.com/) can help), thereby increasing response time, lowering complexity and avoiding a database setup completely.
- You can use server-less architecture to avoid setting up a completely new server to host your **COMMON API**, Firebase Cloud functions or AWS Lambda have generous free tiers to cover a decent amount of traffic.

Comment: The central database approach I can't use. It's an internal app for employees, and the API is in the LAN. The app needs to work even if there is no connection with the central HQ. I can't believe something as easy as a parms file is giving me such a headache

Comment: if you don't want to expose the WHOLE DATASET with the client, params either need to reside somewhere centrally OR you have to individually set the params for each deployment (env variables or hardcoded)

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by exposing the Whole Dataset. What Dataset?

Comment: Why not just do what the answer said except load from a static file?

Answer (score 2):

This can be done simply by making an [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) to a URL (e.g., to a local JSON file), and reading the data contents.

For instance, you could use [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) (supported by [95% browsers](https://caniuse.com/?search=fetch)) to request the config from `<projectroot>/config.json` (which can be unique to each deployment location), and then set the global properties with the result:

```js
// main.js

fetch('config.json')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .catch(error => {
    // ignore any errors
    console.warn(error)
    return {}
  })
  .then(config => {
    Vue.prototype.ApiBaseUrl = config.ApiBaseUrl
    Vue.prototype.PrintDocsFolder = config.PrintDocsFolder
    Vue.prototype.TicketPrintWSocket = config.TicketPrintWSocket

    // initialize app here
    new Vue(...)
  })
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/fetching-config-at-runtime-in-vue-wy7db?file=/src/main.js)